# Spring boot JSON return infinite nested objects

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the following in my code:

CompanyEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company{
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JsonUnwrapped
   private Set<User> users;
}
```

UserEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User{
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name="company_id")
    private Company company;
}
```

CompanyController

```
@GetMapping("/company")
public ResponseEntity<Object> getAllCompanies(){
    List<Company> allCompanies = companyService.findAll();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(allCompanies);

}
```

problem is when i call `/company` in the browser i am getting the `users` object including the company object. something like this

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "company",
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 14,
                "firstName": "Yamen",
                "lastName": "Nassif",
                "company": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "company",
                    "users": [
                        {
                            "id": 14,
                            "firstName": "Yamen",
                            "lastName": "Nassif",
                            "company": {
                                "id": 1,
                                "name": "company",
                                "users": [
```

...

same goes when i getAllUsers companies and users are also exanding.

my database looks just fine.

and its endless and of course Stackoverflow error is in the console. How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this error because of the infinite recursion.

`Company` has a link on `User` and `User` has a link on `Company`.

You have at least two options:

- use [@JsonManagedReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonManagedReference.html) and [@JsonBackReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html) annotation on the relation fields.
- create a pair of DTOs and fill them manually with data from you entities.

e.g.

```
@GetMapping("/company")
public ResponseEntity<Object> getAllCompanies() {
    List<Company> allCompanies = companyService.findAll();
    List<CompanyDto> allCompanyDtoList = convertToCompanyDtoList(allCompanies);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(allCompanyDtoList );
}
```

Personally, I'd prefer the second option, since returning Entities is **NOT** a good practice.

Comment: i tried something different: removing `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` from Company isn`t working and then i have a persistence error

Comment: i mean removing the whole `users` object from Company, but something is getting broken.

Comment: and i am not sure but wont `allCompanies` already break or will already be expanded even without JSONing it ?

Comment: No, acquiring `allCompanies` with the code you've provided in the question won't break anything. This error is about infinite loop when serializing entities to JSON which you return from you rest controller.

Comment: ok thanks, i will try it. but how about removing one of the links from one entity? users from Company as an example ? how can i achieve that without an error ?

Comment: Completely removing the link to `User` from `Company` should indeed solve this problem.

Comment: i accepted it since it worked for me. also removing the users fixed it, weird that i tried it before and it didnt work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use @JsonIgnore annotation to prevent this type of behavior. This usually happens with bidirectional mapping within your entities. It is caused by infinite recursion.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User{
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name="company_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Company company;
}
```